# How to grab an int from my MySQL server via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a novice when it comes to PHP but I don't understand if my syntax is wrong in this statement, or how would I grab an int from my MySQL server.

I know that my server credentials are working fine. How would I fix this statement to give me a returned integer of the number of reviews in the userinfo table?

```
$numberofpreviousreviews = mysql_query("SELECT `number_of_reviews` FROM `userinfo`") or die(mysql_error()); //Check to see how many reviews user has previously created
$amountofreviews = $numberofpreviousreviews + 1;
$query2 = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE userinfo ADD `amountofreviews` VARCHAR(10000)") or die(mysql_error()); //Make another column in database for the new review
```

Comment: You have two answers below that have been waiting for a month, and you just asked a new question. Would you review the below, and upvote/accept as necessary?

Comment: Now downvoted (see above).

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch your results after you run your query. There are several ways to do this but using [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) will work for you.

```
$numberofpreviousreviews = mysql_query("SELECT `number_of_reviews` FROM `userinfo`") or die(mysql_error()); //Check to see how many reviews user has previously created
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($numberofpreviousreviews);
$amountofreviews = $row['number_of_reviews'] + 1;
```

FYI, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are deprecated and going away. You should use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a table `userinfo` which has the following structure and data :

[image]

Scenario **#1** :

If you want to retrieve the all `number_of_reviews`, then do like this,

```
$query = "SELECT `number_of_reviews` FROM `userinfo`";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "Number of reviews : " . $row['number_of_reviews'] . "<br/>";
}
```

It will give you,

```
Number of reviews : 20
Number of reviews : 40
```

Since, the result has many rows, it will display like above.

Scenario **#2**:

If you want to retrieve only the specific `number_of_reviews` for some user id (which is unique). I take `id` as `1` as a example here. Then do like,

```
$query2 =  "SELECT `number_of_reviews` FROM `userinfo` WHERE `id` = 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db,$query2);

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo $row2['number_of_reviews'] . "<br/>";
}
```

This will print,

```
20.
```

Because, `number_of_reviews` is 20 for `id` 1.